# How to delete stack point when using "riscv32/64-unknown-elf-gcc"?

Tags: gcc, riscv32

I designed RISCV32IM processor, and i used "riscv32/64-unknown-elf-gcc" to generate code for test.

It is an OS-less system, and the stack pointer is unnecessary in the instruction code.
However, when compiling as follows, stack point operation is created, and the initial SP value is ZERO, so it malfunctions during instruction code execution.

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -march=rv32im -mabi=ilp32 -nostartfiles -fno-toplevel-reorder -fno-omit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables -O0 -x c  -Ttext 40000000 -Tdata 70000100 -Tbss 70000200 -o main.o main.c
```

The C code is as follows.

```
void    irq1 (void);
void    irq2 (void);
void    irq3 (void);
void    irq4 (void);
void    irq5 (void);
void    irq6 (void);
void    _start(void);

void _start (void)
{
    int     irq;

    IRQ0      = 0;
    DMEM_ROM4 = 0;
    while (1) {
            irq = (int) IRQ0;

            switch (irq) {
                    case 1  : irq1(); break;
                    case 2  : irq2(); break;
                    case 3  : irq3(); break;
                    case 4  : irq4(); break;
                    case 5  : irq5(); break;
                    case 6  : irq6(); break;
                    default : irq1();
            }
    }
}
```

The instruction code generated by compiling is as follows.
In operation "4000005c", it jumps out of the instruction memory area and malfunctions.

I want to delete the SP behavior, how can I do that?
Or is there a way to work normally even with SP?

```
40000000 <_start>:
40000000:       fe010113                addi    sp,sp,-32
40000004:       00112e23                sw      ra,28(sp)
40000008:       00812c23                sw      s0,24(sp)
4000000c:       02010413                addi    s0,sp,32
40000010:       700007b7                lui     a5,0x70000
40000014:       02078793                addi    a5,a5,32 # 70000020 <irq6+0x2ffff854>
40000018:       0007a023                sw      zero,0(a5)
4000001c:       700007b7                lui     a5,0x70000
40000020:       01078793                addi    a5,a5,16 # 70000010 <irq6+0x2ffff844>
40000024:       0007a023                sw      zero,0(a5)
40000028:       700007b7                lui     a5,0x70000
4000002c:       02078793                addi    a5,a5,32 # 70000020 <irq6+0x2ffff854>
40000030:       0007a783                lw      a5,0(a5)
40000034:       fef42623                sw      a5,-20(s0)
40000038:       fec42703                lw      a4,-20(s0)
4000003c:       00600793                li      a5,6
40000040:       04e7e863                bltu    a5,a4,40000090 <_start+0x90>
40000044:       fec42783                lw      a5,-20(s0)
40000048:       00279713                slli    a4,a5,0x2
4000004c:       400017b7                lui     a5,0x40001
40000050:       b6078793                addi    a5,a5,-1184 # 40000b60 <irq6+0x394>
40000054:       00f707b3                add     a5,a4,a5
40000058:       0007a783                lw      a5,0(a5)
4000005c:       00078067                jr      a5
40000060:       038000ef                jal     ra,40000098 <irq1>
40000064:       0300006f                j       40000094 <_start+0x94>
40000068:       180000ef                jal     ra,400001e8 <irq2>
4000006c:       0280006f                j       40000094 <_start+0x94>
```

Comment: The C language was basically invented to target machines that have a stack; for instance, recursion is nearly impossible otherwise.   I very much doubt that gcc has any way to generate code that doesn't use stack.  If you want to program this device in C, I think you should focus your efforts on setting up a stack.  It shouldn't be that hard - identify a sufficiently large block of available memory, and point the stack pointer there before calling the C code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! Can I know how to set the initial stack point and stack memory location?

Comment: I don't know RISC-V very specifically, but normally it's just a matter of moving an appropriate address to the stack pointer register, as part of your assembly-language initialization code.  Deciding what address is appropriate will depend on your device's physical memory layout and how the rest of your memory organization is designed.

Comment: Thank you!!!   Is there no way to use linker_script or compile option?
If ASM code is required, how to compile in a bare-metal environment?

Comment: The linker scripts only affect how the image is laid out; they can't generate the instructions that would actually do the stack setup.  Neither does the compiler; it assumes this has already been done.  Typically you write a small piece of startup code in raw assembly in a separate `.s` file which does the necessary setup and then calls `_start`. Assemble it to an object file, and write your linker script so that execution begins at your startup code.